# Facebook Graph API - group URL to ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

While some group URLs come in the format of www.facebook.com/groups/%ID%/ other come in the format of www.facebook.com/groups/%SOME_STRING%/. For example  http://www.facebook.com/groups/2261122614/ vs. http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/.

In the former case it's very easy to programmatically extract the Graph API ID from the URL. How can that be done for URLs of the latter case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out! Do this:

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=[ALIAS]&type=group

Comment: That´s not 100% correct because it will return an array of Groups witch are related to the ALIAS! I mean, it´s a search and doest not return the exactly group!

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.wallflux.com/facebook_id/

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't return an id for  http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ . See http://www.wallflux.com/feed/146797922030397

Comment: The ID is 146797922030397. If you uncheck the checkbox it would have returned you just the number, not the whole wallflux.

Comment: Nice! The question is how can I do independently of Wallflux using only the Graph API. As far as I see, they do not provide the code used for their service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this website. It works for groups and profiles
http://findmyfbid.com/